# Compiling C# projects on Linux with dependencies

Tags: c#, linux, mono, xbuild

I am trying to compile OpenLR on Linux (Ubuntu) using Mono, however, I run into the problem of the compiler (`xbuild`) not being able to find the project's dependency, Itinero.

I used nuget.exe to install Itinero, but it didn't work. I also tried googling for something like Classpath in C#, but found that C# doesn't have it.

Is there a way to make the `xbuild` see the dependencies? How can I specify the paths to the directories where those dependencies are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do a package restore:

```
git clone https://github.com/itinero/OpenLR.git
cd OpenLR
nuget restore OpenLR.sln
xbuild OpenLR.sln
```

It should compile with zero errors, there are 27 warnings that need cleaned up in the code....

Note: Make sure the you are on an updated/modern install of Mono as if you are using the default Mono package from Ubuntu you might need to update it:

Ref: http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin

Comment: Great! It mostly worked. Now I get 1 compilation error: CSC: error CS2001: Source file `Binary/PolygonLocationTests.cs' could not be found and 25 warnings.

Comment: I think I see the problem. The file name is actually PolygonLocationtests.cs, with cmall t in Tests, which causes problems on a case sensitive file system.